# While performing contrastive divergnece for the Boltzmann machine, i am getting the following error. i am using the latest version of pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning

```
class RBM():
    def __init__(self, nv, nh):
        self.W = torch.randn(nh, nv)
        self.a = torch.randn(1, nh)
        self.b = torch.randn(1, nv)
    def sample_h(self, x):
        wx = torch.mm(x, self.W.t())
        activation = wx + self.a.expand_as(wx)
        p_h_given_v = torch.sigmoid(activation)
        return p_h_given_v, torch.bernoulli(p_h_given_v)
    def sample_v(self, y):
        wy = torch.mm(y, self.W)
        activation = wy + self.b.expand_as(wy)
        p_v_given_h = torch.sigmoid(activation)
        return p_v_given_h, torch.bernoulli(p_v_given_h)
    def train(self, v0, vk, ph0, phk):
        self.W += torch.mm(v0.t(), ph0) - torch.mm(vk.t(), phk)
        self.b += torch.sum((v0 - vk), 0)
        self.a += torch.sum((ph0 - phk), 0)
```

Error :

in train(self, v0, vk, ph0, phk)

```
     19         return p_v_given_h, torch.bernoulli(p_v_given_h)
     20     def train(self, v0, vk, ph0, phk):
---> 21         self.W += torch.mm(v0.t(), ph0) - torch.mm(vk.t(), phk)
     22         self.b += torch.sum((v0 - vk), 0)
     23         self.a += torch.sum((ph0 - phk), 0)
```

RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (1682) must match the existing size (100) at non-singleton dimension 1

Answer (score 9):

`print(rbm.W.size())` will show you torch.Size([100, 1682])

`print((torch.mm(v0.t(), ph0)-torch.mm(vk.t(), phk)).size())` will show you torch.Size([1682, 100])

so it looks like it should be something like that:

```
self.W += (torch.mm(v0.t(), ph0) - torch.mm(vk.t(), phk)).t()
```

instead of `self.W += torch.mm(v0.t(), ph0) - torch.mm(vk.t(), phk)`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
self.W += torch.mm (v0.t(), ph0) - torch.mm (vk.t(), phk)
```

To this:

```
self.W += (torch.mm(v0.t(), ph0) - torch.mm(vk.t(), phk)).t()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
def __init__(self, nv, nh):
    self.W = torch.randn(nv, nh) # was torch.randn(nh, nv)
    self.a = torch.randn(1, nh)
    self.b = torch.randn(1, nv)
def sample_h(self, x):
    wx = torch.mm(x, self.W) # was torch.mm(x, self.W.t())    
    activation = wx + self.a.expand_as(wx)
    p_h_given_v = torch.sigmoid(activation)
    return p_h_given_v, torch.bernoulli(p_h_given_v)
def sample_v(self, y):
    wy = torch.mm(y, self.W.t()) # was torch.mm(y, self.W)  
    activation = wy + self.b.expand_as(wy)
    p_v_given_h = torch.sigmoid(activation)
    return p_v_given_h, torch.bernoulli(p_v_given_h)
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55959716/edit) some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have such dimensional error, try to write dimensions of all variable in front of them. As mentioned above you have to take transport in first line of train function.

```
class RBM():
    def __init__(self, nv, nh):
        self.W = torch.randn(nh, nv)   #100*1682                 
        self.a = torch.randn(1, nh)    #1*100                       
        self.b = torch.randn(1, nv)    #1*1682                   
    def sample_h(self, x):                                     
        wx = torch.mm(x, self.W.t())    #100*1682 * 1682*100 = 100*100
        activation = wx + self.a.expand_as(wx)                  
        p_h_given_v = torch.sigmoid(activation)     #100*100
        return p_h_given_v, torch.bernoulli(p_h_given_v)
    def sample_v(self, y):                                      
        wy = torch.mm(y, self.W)    #100*100 * 100*1682 = 100*1682
        activation = wy + self.b.expand_as(wy)                  
        p_v_given_h = torch.sigmoid(activation)     #100*1682
        return p_v_given_h, torch.bernoulli(p_v_given_h)
    def train(self, v0, vk, ph0, phk):                         
        self.W += (torch.mm(v0.t(), ph0)- torch.mm(vk.t(), phk)).t()    #100*1682 
                             #!= 1682*100 * 100*100 - 1682*100 * 100*100 = 1682*100
        self.b += torch.sum((v0-vk), 0)                            
        self.a += torch.sum((ph0-phk), 0)
```